# BigQuery - Querying optional fields on dataset's schemas

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query like this one, in **Standard SQL**:

```
SELECT record.field1, record.field2 
FROM dataset.*
WHERE record.field2 == 'something'
```

but some of my tables doesn't have on schema this `field2`.

I`m getting that error:

> Field name field2 does not exist in STRUCT field at ... [17:34]

Anyone knows how can I query put some optional clause to be evaluated **only** when the field exists in the schema?

Comment: 1) if you expect this to happen in pure BQ SQL - it is not doable so you can post feature request using the [BigQuery issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/) 2) meantime you can write simple code in client of your choice to read schema of the tables in your dataset and act accordinly (but looks like it is not what you want - so see previous bullet) 3) btw - `==` is not proper use in BQ SQL -> you should use `=`  ;

Comment: Yes... I'm building this query ad-hoc to calculate some general metrics, so writing some code using the API was not my first option. If there is no FR about this, I'll open one. Thanks, Mikhail!

Comment: I think there is potentially related FR that can help in  your scenario - to have ability to pass generic objects into UDF (templating) - you can try to search for it in issue tracker. if I am not mistaken - it was filed by @ElliottBrossard some time ago based on some another post in SO

Comment: I don't think templated UDFs will help here - the filter on record.field2 is problematic.

Comment: i had in mind idea (not well thought through though) of not using filtering on record.field2 in sql but rather leverage templating and do validation inside js udf with try catch ... . but overall agree - chances are not good that it can be materialized :o) but usually i am on optimistic side

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I have is to convert the `STRUCT` `record` to string and then reparse, i.e. the following query illustrates the approach:

```
with
 t1 as (select 'foo' field1, 'a' field2),
 t2 as (select 'bar' field1)
select 
  trim(split(f)[safe_offset(0)], '()') field1,
  trim(split(f)[safe_offset(1)], '()') field2 
from
(select format("%t", t1) f from t1 union all
 select format("%t", t2) f from t2)
```

It produces:

```
Row field1  field2   
1   bar     null     
2   foo     a
```

To apply this solution to the original problem:

```
SELECT
  trim(split(f)[safe_offset(0)], '()') field1,
  trim(split(f)[safe_offset(1)], '()') field2 
FROM (
  select format("%t", t) f from `dataset.*` t
)
WHERE record.field2 == 'something'
```

Comment: but the whole trick/question is in `how to actually do this conversion` for all tables in given dataset as apart of ad-hoc? :o)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that ?

Comment: I was just wondering - how to actually apply this approach to specific use case in original question?

Comment: Updated answer to show how it applies to the original question.

Comment: Thank you Mosha. Somehow i am not getting how I would apply this for given use case. WIll check again later :o)